# How can we verify the links shown using selenium rc mouseOver event

Tags: java, selenium-rc

My Application has too many links. I need to do a **mouseOver** on each **element** and need verify the links shown at the bottom of the page. I've tried with **selenium** as follows,

```
selenium.mouseOver("id=logo");
assertTrue(selenium.isVisible("//*[contains(text(), '/webshop')]"));
```

But it didn't succeeded.

I have tried searching but didn't find any matching help for **selenium rc**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, what you are looking for is not a mouseover issue,  you want to know what the link points to.  So you need to use getAttribute function and fetch the href attribute which would give you the link that appears on the browser status bar...something like selenium.getattribute("/@href"), store the attribute in a string and do a string comparison with expected result.

Comment: I am writing a JBehave story. Where the When case is to do a mousehover and Then is to verify the link displayed.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to do a mouseOver on each element and need verify the links
>   shown at the bottom of the page.

Bottom means where you are getting those links? Can you paste a link to the web page where you testing this code? So that it will be easy to solve.

Comment: This should really be a comment rather than an "answer".

Comment: yes. u r right. i tried to ask it as a comment only. But am not permitted to add comment(as am new here).

Comment: Goto www.google.co.in and do mouse over on any of the languages shown. On the bottom left we could see links it points for each language.

Comment: The main problem here is `selenium.mouseover("//a[text()='Telugu']/@href");` [i tried it on `www.google.co.in` page] executing fine (means not showing any error.) but no link is showing at the bottom after executing this line.

Comment: I've tried it with FF10. But I didn't find any link displayed at the bottom.

Comment: Can you do one thing..? debug your code and execute this line selenium.mouseOver("id=logo");. Just see whether the link is showing at the bottom or not. if it is showing the link at the bottom, then we can verify it by selenium.isTextpresent().

Comment: Yes. i tried it in FF12 also in google chrome. it is not showing any link at the bottom.